# If statement not working as it schould

Tags: java

This part of my code:

```
private void getSize(){
    Size = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:/DogDateBase/datebase.txt"));
        String line = rd.readLine();
        while(line != null){                
            if(line.equals("small")||line.equals("big")){ 
                Size.add(line);  // The if statement is not working
            }
            line=rd.readLine();
        }
        rd.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't find DateBase");
    }
```

The problem is that when I output(System.out.println()) the ArrayList Size it writes on the screen only one time "small".But on the file there are 60 lines and obout 10-15 times there is the word small or big. Why those it add to the Array list only once?? Can anybody help me??

Comment: May be space issue or case issue? try to trim the line and see.

Comment: You're reading the whole line, so maybe there are more words per line than just "small" and "big"? try using `String.contains()` instead of `String.equals()`

Comment: Could you provide an input file, that reproduces your problems? Make it as easy as possible.

Comment: Given the input that you say you have, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code you've posted. Which likely means that the input is different to what your code is expecting. Post a sample of the datebase.txt file that you're using (copy and paste it, *don't* write it manually). @Nambari is probably correct and you need to use a combination of something like `line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("small")`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
if(line.contains("small")||line.contains("big"))
```

Or if you are super! sure there's only "small" or "big" on a line:

```
if(line.trim().equals("small")||line.trim().equals("big"))
```

In case there are white spaces